# Using Powershell to open local .htm file and get values via XPath

Tags: html, powershell

I'm new to Powershell and am trying to use it to open up an existing .htm file and then obtain some values from that file via XPath to then use elsewhere.

This is where I'm currently at with the script:

```
$localHtmlFile = 'myfile.htm'
$html = New-Object -com "HTMLFILE"
$html.write((Get-Content $localHtmlFile | Out-String))

$html.AllElements |
        Where XPath -eq "html/body/h4[1]/strong" |
        Select -First 1 -ExpandProperty innerText
```

The problem I'm facing is that I'm getting the following error when I run this:

Exception calling "write" with "1" argument(s): "Type mismatch

I have tried multiple .htm files. I'm using Powershell v4.0.

Any ideas? I'm sure it's something obvious but I can't fathom it. Also, I haven't managed to test the XPath part yet as I can't get beyond the write exception. So I'm not entirely sure that code is correct.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your myfile.htm is a valid XML document you can use `Select-XML` cmdlet to query nodes in your XML tree.

for instance if your myfile.htm is as such

```
<html>
  <head>
   <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
   <h4><strong>My First Heading</strong></h4>
  </body>
</html>
```

then you can query the contents of `h4` with `Select-XML` like

`PS C:\> $h4txt = (Select-Xml -Path .\myfile.htm -XPath //body/h4).Node.InnerText`

`PS C:\> $h4txt
 My First Heading`

You can refer [here](http://zvon.org/xxl/XPathTutorial/General/examples.html) for XPath examples on Selections

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This looks like a good technique. Doesn't seem to be working for me but I think that is because my htm document isn't valid XML.

Comment: @Phonesis I'm having the same issue and the same problem ^^^^. Did you find any solution?

Comment: I ended up doing it like this: 
(Get-Content $htmlfile) | Foreach-Object {
    $_ -replace $valuetoreplace, $newvalue`
    } | Set-Content $graph